# 18.04 How to install new kernel with samba service failing error code 1?

Tags: apt, package-management, samba, update-manager

The software updater advises that there's a new kernel to install but 0 bytes is given for the download size. It goes thru the process, asks to restart the system. Running apt update and apt upgrade in the terminal returns this output:

---

```
$ sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libnautilus-extension1a nautilus nautilus-data unattended-upgrades
4 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 930 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 nautilus amd64 1:3.26.4-0~ubuntu18.04.2 [808 kB]
Get:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 nautilus-data all 1:3.26.4-0~ubuntu18.04.2 [69.0 kB]
Get:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libnautilus-extension1a amd64 1:3.26.4-0~ubuntu18.04.2 [15.2 kB]
Get:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 unattended-upgrades all 1.1ubuntu1.18.04.6 [37.7 kB]
Fetched 930 kB in 1s (1,339 kB/s)           
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 204408 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../nautilus_1%3a3.26.4-0~ubuntu18.04.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nautilus (1:3.26.4-0~ubuntu18.04.2) over (1:3.26.4-0~ubuntu18.04.1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../nautilus-data_1%3a3.26.4-0~ubuntu18.04.2_all.deb ...
Unpacking nautilus-data (1:3.26.4-0~ubuntu18.04.2) over (1:3.26.4-0~ubuntu18.04.1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../libnautilus-extension1a_1%3a3.26.4-0~ubuntu18.04.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libnautilus-extension1a:amd64 (1:3.26.4-0~ubuntu18.04.2) over (1:3.26.4-0~ubuntu18.04.1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../unattended-upgrades_1.1ubuntu1.18.04.6_all.deb ...
Unpacking unattended-upgrades (1.1ubuntu1.18.04.6) over (1.1ubuntu1.18.04.5) ...
Setting up nautilus-data (1:3.26.4-0~ubuntu18.04.2) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.60ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-20) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.23-1ubuntu3.18.04.1) ...
Processing triggers for libglib2.0-0:i386 (2.56.3-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) ...
Processing triggers for libglib2.0-0:amd64 (2.56.3-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libnautilus-extension1a:amd64 (1:3.26.4-0~ubuntu18.04.2) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (237-3ubuntu10.6) ...
Setting up unattended-upgrades (1.1ubuntu1.18.04.6) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2ubuntu0.1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-11ubuntu1.1) ...
Setting up samba (2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.2) ...
Samba is not being run as an AD Domain Controller.
Please ignore the following error about deb-systemd-helper not finding samba-ad-dc.service.
Job for smbd.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status smbd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript smbd, action "start" failed.
● smbd.service - Samba SMB Daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/smbd.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2018-11-16 14:11:06 EST; 7ms ago
     Docs: man:smbd(8)
           man:samba(7)
           man:smb.conf(5)
  Process: 22773 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/smbd --foreground --no-process-group $SMBDOPTIONS (code=exited, status=255)
 Main PID: 22773 (code=exited, status=255)

Nov 16 14:11:06 imager42 smbd[22773]:   Ignoring unknown parameter "update encrypted"
Nov 16 14:11:06 imager42 smbd[22773]: [2018/11/16 14:11:06.599969,  0] ../source3/auth/auth_util.c:778(get_guest_info3)
Nov 16 14:11:06 imager42 smbd[22773]:   SamInfo3_for_guest: Unable to locate guest account [smbguest]!
Nov 16 14:11:06 imager42 smbd[22773]: [2018/11/16 14:11:06.600037,  0] ../source3/auth/auth_util.c:846(make_new_session_info_guest)
Nov 16 14:11:06 imager42 smbd[22773]:   get_guest_info3 failed with NT_STATUS_NO_SUCH_USER
Nov 16 14:11:06 imager42 smbd[22773]: [2018/11/16 14:11:06.600077,  0] ../source3/smbd/server.c:2011(main)
Nov 16 14:11:06 imager42 smbd[22773]:   ERROR: failed to setup guest info.
Nov 16 14:11:06 imager42 systemd[1]: smbd.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=255/n/a
Nov 16 14:11:06 imager42 systemd[1]: smbd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Nov 16 14:11:06 imager42 systemd[1]: Failed to start Samba SMB Daemon.
dpkg: error processing package samba (--configure):
 installed samba package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.17-2) ...
Setting up nautilus (1:3.26.4-0~ubuntu18.04.2) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of system-config-samba:
 system-config-samba depends on samba; however:
  Package samba is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package system-config-samba (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                          Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 samba
 system-config-samba
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

---

Running service samba restart yields this result:

```
$ service smbd restart
Job for smbd.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status smbd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up samba (2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.2) ...
Samba is not being run as an AD Domain Controller.
Please ignore the following error about deb-systemd-helper not finding samba-ad-dc.service.
Job for smbd.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status smbd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript smbd, action "start" failed.
● smbd.service - Samba SMB Daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/smbd.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2018-11-16 14:26:04 EST; 7ms ago
     Docs: man:smbd(8)
           man:samba(7)
           man:smb.conf(5)
  Process: 23721 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/smbd --foreground --no-process-group $SMBDOPTIONS (code=exited, status=255)
 Main PID: 23721 (code=exited, status=255)

Nov 16 14:26:04 imager42 smbd[23721]:   Ignoring unknown parameter "update encrypted"
Nov 16 14:26:04 imager42 smbd[23721]: [2018/11/16 14:26:04.912861,  0] ../source3/auth/auth_util.c:778(get_guest_info3)
Nov 16 14:26:04 imager42 smbd[23721]:   SamInfo3_for_guest: Unable to locate guest account [smbguest]!
Nov 16 14:26:04 imager42 smbd[23721]: [2018/11/16 14:26:04.912925,  0] ../source3/auth/auth_util.c:846(make_new_session_info_guest)
Nov 16 14:26:04 imager42 smbd[23721]:   get_guest_info3 failed with NT_STATUS_NO_SUCH_USER
Nov 16 14:26:04 imager42 smbd[23721]: [2018/11/16 14:26:04.912964,  0] ../source3/smbd/server.c:2011(main)
Nov 16 14:26:04 imager42 smbd[23721]:   ERROR: failed to setup guest info.
Nov 16 14:26:04 imager42 systemd[1]: smbd.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=255/n/a
Nov 16 14:26:04 imager42 systemd[1]: smbd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Nov 16 14:26:04 imager42 systemd[1]: Failed to start Samba SMB Daemon.
dpkg: error processing package samba (--configure):
 installed samba package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of system-config-samba:
 system-config-samba depends on samba; however:
  Package samba is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package system-config-samba (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                          Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 samba
 system-config-samba
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

---

None of the other questions seem to address this.

Comment: Do you use an LDAP backend for samba ?

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding. No, not to my knowledge.

Comment: Do you use samba at all?